# get URL from browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, browser, mozilla

Is possible with java know which pages web are open?

Example:
my tabs:

facebook.com || stackoverflow.com/ ||google.com  ||+||

Example of what I want.

Output from java:

```
Site: 

http://www.facebook.com

http://www.stackoverflow.com

http://www.google.com
```

I can put the url in browser using this code:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL("http://www.google.com").toURI());
```

**But how I get?**

Comment: may be u need to make a browser extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard Java API for this. Also there is no standard API from the browsers' part to provide this info toward other applications.

So in short you can't do this. In case of some operating systems and in case of some browsers you might be able to get this by executing certain OS commands and parsing the output, but that is just hacky and won't work in all cases.